# Databricks Connect test does not start - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

After running Databricks-connect configure I am trying to run test but it always fails to start with:

```
* PySpark is installed at c:\users\username\.conda\envs\dbconnect\lib\site-packages\pyspark
* Checking SPARK_HOME
* Checking java version
java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
* Skipping scala command test on Windows
* Testing python command
19/07/25 15:11:15 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name SparkStatusTracker for source because neither spark.metrics.namespace nor spark.app.id is set.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4041. Attempting port 4042.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4042. Attempting port 4043.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4043. Attempting port 4044.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4044. Attempting port 4045.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4045. Attempting port 4046.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4046. Attempting port 4047.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4047. Attempting port 4048.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4048. Attempting port 4049.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4049. Attempting port 4050.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4050. Attempting port 4051.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4051. Attempting port 4052.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4052. Attempting port 4053.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4053. Attempting port 4054.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4054. Attempting port 4055.
19/07/25 15:11:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4055. Attempting port 4056.
19/07/25 15:11:17 ERROR SparkUI: Failed to bind SparkUI
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind: Service 'SparkUI' failed after 16 retries (starting from 4040)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'SparkUI' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
```

This is the first error raised, but I think the ones that follow are related to this. Can anyone tell me how to set the SparkUI port through databricks-connect? Worth noting that netstat -an shows these ports as available. I get this same error if I run as admin or not.